# Preventing GC from releasing object until a process completes

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Consider a process that is running for a very long time in my application, which has an
object. Will calling `SuppressFinalize()` ensure that the GC doesn't release the resources
until the end of process?

Comment: `SuppressFinalize()` does not protect object from being collected. It just means that finalizer won't be called for this object (if it exists). If object is used (has root references) it won't be released otherwise why do you need unused object?

Comment: Why do you still need something that you do no longer reference?

Comment: If there is a running thread which has access to the object (a local or parameter *somewhere* in the stack of function calls) then it will not be disposed. The stack of every thread is a GC root. If you are passing to PInvoke and are not storing it in the managed stack then you need `GC.KeepAlive` otherwise it's not necessary

Answer (score 1):

In short: No, it does something different.

`SuppressFinalize()` tells the GC not to call the finalization method of your object, when garbage collected, it does not prevent the object from being garbage collected.

For your scenario, you need to store all your objects somewhere and clean them after your long-running task is completed. Best Practice is to use a DI (dependency injection) framework.

.Net core has an integrated DI framework that will easily do what you want. You  would need to register your class as scoped. Create a scope, create your object inside the scope, start your long-running task, dispose the scope after the task is completed.

SuppressFinilize: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=net-6.0

.net core DI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0